# Running into some problems in Excel with formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have been given this Excel file as homework and there's a few tasks I need to do but I've run into some problems.
One task I have problems with is as follows: What countries are not members of the European Union but members of the European Economic Area?
I have used the following formula: `=IF(G2:G46="No",IF(H2:H46="Yes",A2:A46,""),"").` 
The results seem to be good but they are listed all over the place. I want them to be listed in a column below one another.

Another problem I have is with the following question: What countries have a capital city whose population is larger than 2 million people?
In this case I have used the following formula but it returned a bunch of missing values.
`=INDEX($A$2:$A$46,MATCH(IF(Europe_city!B2:B46>2000000,Europe_capital_city!A2:A46,""),$B$2:$B$46,0))`

The last problem I have is with this question: How many dwarf states are there in Europe? We call a country a dwarf state if its area is smaller than 1000km²  or its population is smaller than 500 000 people.
I have solved this problem using to formulas but I am wondering if it's possible to do it with only one.
`=IF(OR(C2<1000;D2<500000);1;"")` 
`=SUM(S2:S46)`

I have attached the file to maybe further help understanding the problem.
Thank you for your help in advance, I know it's a lot!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1XCMCF74qiRGD9xUPyZYCORlzYdigo9-Y

Comment: `FILTER()` formula may help you.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a list of data, you want to have an answer on some questions, which can be found with the formulas you mentioned, but you don't know how to proceed?

Well, simply put the mentioned formulas in helper columns and start up an autofilter, based on the results of your formulas. (Applying the autofilter shows you the amount of results in the statusbar)

In case you don't want this (e.g. you want a list of dwarf states without filtering), then you need to use VBA and program the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, a simple If statement can list then in the same column.
For the second one, i used a Index match formula to fetch the populations from the other sheet and then applied conditional formatting to highlight relevant values.
For the final one, a Countifs statement can combine the function of both.

```
=IF(AND(G2="Nem",H2="Igen"),A2,"")

=INDEX(Europe_capital_city!B$2:B$46,MATCH(Europe_country!B2,Europe_capital_city!A$2:A$46,0))

=COUNTIFS(C2:C46,"<1000",D2:D46,"<500000")
```

[File here](https://file.re/2020/11/23/stack-void/)